# jQuery is not working in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to write a code which retrieves values from databases and uses `slidetoggle()` to slide them on screen.

This is **.html** file without database retrieval which works perfectly:

```html
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Mohit\Desktop\jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="handleChange();">

<label><input type='checkbox' onchange='handleChange();'>Check box</label>

<script>
function handleChange()
{
    $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle();
}
</script>
<div class="slideTogglebox">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Judge1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Judge2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I wrote this **.jsp** file including above jQuery with database retrieval, but in output it is showing only retrieved values, but `slidetoggle()` function is not working.

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Mohit\Desktop\jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function handleChange()
{

    $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle();

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="handleChange();">
<%
    try{
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs;

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aniket","root","");
        String strsql=null;
        strsql="select * from projects";
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(strsql);
        while(rs.next())
        {%><br><input type='checkbox' onchange='handleChange();'><%
            out.print("CO"+rs.getInt(1)+"");
            out.print(rs.getString(2));
        }   
       }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println(e);
        }
%>
    <div class="slideTogglebox">
    <%
            Connection conn1 = null;
                ResultSet rs1;
            conn1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aniket","root","");
            String strsql1=null;
            strsql1="select * from judges";
            Statement stmt=conn1.createStatement();

            rs1=stmt.executeQuery(strsql1);
            while(rs1.next())
            {%><br><input type='checkbox'><%
            out.print(rs1.getInt(1));
            out.print(rs1.getString(2));
        }%>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) url to the jQuery script file, not an absolute filesystem path. Ideally, this would be something like

```
<script src="/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

where the jQuery script is part of your app.

If you only ever want to run this on your local machine, you can stick with the filesystem path however it should use the [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

```
<script src="file:///C:/Users/Mohit/Desktop/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

An even better solution would be to use the [Google CDN link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery), eg

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

One more thing, you should really add a doctype to the top of your document. I recommend HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, Google CDN link worked.                                               and thank you for correction, I will learn to avoid Javascript in JSP.

Comment: @user2213232 Why on Earth would you want to avoid JavaScript in JSP? Did you mean "Java"?

Comment: oh sorry, yes I mean "java".